# An exception occured while executing "DRILL Through" query

Tags: jquery, ajax, mdx

While executing "Drill Through" query by using ajax post am getting the below exception([Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVX0l.png)). I'm using the `msmdpump.dll` and SQL server 2012. I have attached code snippet below. Using simple "DrillThrogh" query in SSAS 2012 getting the below exception ([SSAS2012_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCnyZ.png))

```
<script>
var query = "DRILLTHROUGH Select([Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&amp;[2002],[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]) on 0 From [Adventure Works]RETURN[Reseller Sales].[Reseller Sales Amount],[Reseller Sales].[Reseller Order Quantity],[Reseller Sales].[Reseller Extended Amount],[Reseller Sales].[Reseller Tax Amount],[Reseller Sales].[Reseller Freight Cost],[Reseller Sales].[Discount Amount],[Reseller Sales].[Reseller Total Product Cost],[Reseller Sales].[Reseller Standard Product Cost],[$Date].[Date]";
var data = "<Envelope xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> <Header></Header> <Body> <Execute xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis\"> <Command> <Statement> " + query + " </Statement> </Command> <Properties> <PropertyList> <Catalog>Adventure Works DW</Catalog></PropertyList> </Properties></Execute> </Body> </Envelope>";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/Olap/msmdpump.dll",
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: data,
    complete: ej.proxy(function (onComplete) {


    }, this),
    success: $.proxy(onSuccess, this),
    error: $.proxy(function (msg, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }, this)
});

function onSuccess(e) {

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following section need to be standard mdx? - it isn't standard:

```
Select([Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&amp;[2002],[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]) on 0 From [Adventure Works]
```